# Proof that Legendre Polynomials are Complete

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, reference-request, eigenfunctions, legendre-polynomials

Can somebody either point me to, or show me a proof, that the [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), or any set of eigenfunctions, are complete?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68822/2451

Comment: By the link on that answer, it seems like they suggest that given the finite dimensional spectral theorem, we should generalize to infinite dimension to state that we can find a "basis". I don't know why we can generalize, nor does that imply that the Legendre Polynomials are *the* basis, although they are orthogonal-just because there are infinitely many doesn't mean that they are a "basis" right?

Comment: For them to be a basis you need to be able to write your function as a linear combination of the legendre polynomials.

Comment: There is also a spectral theorem for normal operators in the infinite dimensional case. Note however, that the spectrum or a part of the spectrum might be continous. In this case you don't have a complete set of eigenfunctions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that B_Scheiner's answer could be condensed to the statement that it depends on it being of [Sturm–Liouville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) type.

Once you have a linear inner product and resolution of the identity, then
$$\begin{align}f(x) &= \int\!dx'\, \delta(x-x') f(x')\\
& =  \int\!dx'\, \left[  \sum_{n} u_n(x) u_n(x') w(x) \right] f(x')\\
& = \sum_n u_n(x) \left[\int\!dx'\,  u_n(x') w(x)  f(x') \right]\\
& = \sum_n u_n(x) f_n
\end{align}$$

Thus all you really need to do is prove that the set of all Legendre polynomials satisfies $\sum_n p_n(x) p_n(y) = \delta(x-y)$ over the domain.

This properly belongs in math.se though, but I suppose it's something every physicist should know.

Answer (score 9):

We follow J. Weidmanns *[Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461260299)*. We find in section $3.2$ *Orthonormal systems and orthonormal bases*:

> **Example 6**: In $L_2(-1,1)$ the set $F=\{f_n:n\in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ with $f_n(x)=x^n$ is a linearly independent system.
>
> The application of the *[Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)* 
>   provides an orthonormal system (ONS) $M=\{p_n:n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$, where $p_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^na_{n,j}x^j$ holds with $a_{n,n}>0$; i.e., $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with a positive leading coefficient.
>
> These polynomials are called the *[Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)*. As $F$ is total, the Legendre polynomials constitute an orthonormal basis (ONB) in $L_2(-1,1)$.
>
> The polynomials $p_n$ can be given explicitly:
>   \begin{align*}
> p_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n,\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}_0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

$L_2(M)$ denotes a *[Lebesgue space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)* for a Lebesgue measurable subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$. If $B$ is a subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then it is said to be *total* if the *linear hull* $L(B)$ (the set of finite linear combinations of elements of $B$) is dense in $H$, i.e. ${\overline{L(B)}}=H$.

In order to prove formula (1) it is sufficient to show that the expression given for $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ whose leading coefficient is positive and that $\langle p_n,p_m\rangle=\delta_{n,m}$.

> The first assertion is obvious. For $j<m$ we obtain by a $(j+1)$-fold integration by parts (the integrated terms vanish) that
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{-1}^1x^jp_m(x)\,dx&=C_m\int_{-1}^1x^j\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\,dx\\
> &=\ldots\\
> &=C_m(-1)^{j+1}\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{j+1}}{dx^{j+1}}(x^j)\frac{d^{m-j-1}}{dx^{m-j-1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\,dx\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}
>   This implies that $\langle p_n,p_m\rangle=0$ for $n\ne m$. It remains to prove that $\|p_n\|=1$. By integration by parts we obtain that
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{-1}^1&\left[\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n\right]^2\,dx\\
> &=(-1)^n\int_{-1}^1\left(x^2-1\right)^n\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\left(x^2-1\right)^n\,dx\\
> &=(2n)!\int_{-1}^1(1-x)^n(1+x)^n\,dx\\
> &=(2n)!\frac{n}{n+1}\int_{-1}^1(1-x)^{n-1}(1+x)^{n+1}\,dx\\
> &=(2n)!\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\int_{-1}^1(1-x)^{n-2}(1+x)^{n+2}\,dx\\
> &=\ldots\\
> &=(2n)!\frac{n(n-1)\cdots 1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots 2n}\int_{-1}^1(1+x)^{2n}\,dx\\
> &=(2n)!\frac{1}{2n+1}\left[(1+x)^{2n+1}\right]_{-1}^1\\
> &=(n!)^2(2n+1)^{-1}2^{2n+1}
> \end{align*}
>
> From this it follows that $\|p_n\|=1$ and the Legendre polynomials constitute an ONB in $L_2(-1,1)$.

Comment: I do not understand the justification of $$(-1)^n\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^{n}dx=(2n)!\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x)^{n}(1+x)^{n}dx$$  since by the binomial theorem $(x^2-1)^{n}=\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}x^{2n-2k}$ then $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^{n}=(2n)!$ what implies $$(-1)^n\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^{n}dx=(-1)^{n}(2n)!\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)dx=(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!\frac{4}{3}.$$ Which is different from $(n!)^{2}(2n+1)^{-1}2^{2n+1}$.

Comment: I already saw the problem, the expression $$(-1)^n\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^{n}dx$$ is not correct, the correct thing is $$(-1)^n\int_{-1}^{1}(x^2-1)^{n}\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^{n}dx.$$

Comment: @DiegoFonseca: Great! Thanks a lot for taking the time and finding the mistake. Typo corrected. Best,

Answer (score 4):

Let $M_n = \int_a^b |f(x)-\sum_i a_i f_i(x)|^2 dx$ where $f_i$ is an orthonormal set of functions (such as the legendre polynomials). The set of $ f_i$ is complete if there is a set of coefficients $\{a_i\}$ such that $\lim_{n -> \infty} M_n=0$. If you can show that you can approximate a function on a closed interval in a way such that $M_n$ goes to zero as n goes to infinity then you are golden ( maybe look into the wierstrass approximation theorem).

I should mention that the legendre polynomials are part of what are termed Sturm -Louiville problems, and your question could be generalized to a much larger set of polynomials.

Comment: You can use `$$` to get centered equations (e.g. `$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}M_n=0$$`)

Comment: A lot of the beauty of quantum mechanics comes from the properties of Strum-Liouville systems. I would recommend "Mathematics of Classical and Quantum Physics " by Byron and Fuller chapter 5.

Comment: Thanks I couldnt remember how to do that.

Comment: Can I do this for a general function though? I have yet to take any analysis courses-however I feel like you would have to put in some specific function to show it converges...

Comment: Forgive me because its been a while since my last analysis class, but I believe that as long as the function is continuous, and bounded on the interval you  should be able to prove it in general.The chapter I recommended in byron and fuller really has a good discussion on these topics that should be readable even if you dont have any analysis background.

Comment: How though? I don't know how you would progress from having a $f(x)$ floating around.

Comment: I'll get back to you on that soon

Comment: An alternative reference about proving the completeness of Strum-Liouville eigenfunction is Hilbert and Courant, Methods of mathematical physics, vol I, section VI-3

Comment: Has this question been answered satisfactorily yet? I don't feel like it has, but I'm also a little lost in the analysis.

Comment: @Anonymous: Isn't the other answer complete and correct?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest proof that the Legendre polynomials are complete is with the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem.2C_real_version). You just have to prove that linear combinations of Legendre functions are a unital subalgebra of the continuous functions that separates points.

To prove a collection of eigenvectors forms a basis, take a look at Theorem 7 in Appendix D.6 in Lawrence Evans' Partial Differential Equations. This should get you started. It gives conditions that guarantee this: Just apply the theorem to the solution operator of a differential equation.