# What's the connection between Legendre polynomials, Associated Legendre polynomials, and Sphereical Harmonic?

Tags: calculus, definition, graphing-functions, symmetry, legendre-polynomials

[Associated Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) and [Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) are strongly connected. From what I read, Legendre polynomials is a special case of Associated Legendre polynomials where $m=0$. Thus the Orthogonality and parity condition followed from Associated Legendre Polynomial.

From alexjo's answer in this post [Associated Legendre Polynomials!?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736171/associated-legendre-polynomials) , Associated Legendre polynomial was the solution with "a separation ansatz", and Legendre polynomial was the solution with azimuthal symmetry. [Spherical Harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) was then introduced with Associated Legendre polynomial multiply by a complex phase.

1. Is the above summary correct? or have I missed something?
2. From this post [Proof that Legendre Polynomials are Complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591406/proof-that-legendre-polynomials-are-complete), Legendre Polynomial itself had already formed a complete basis, so why do we need Associated Legendre Polynomial? Isn't it too excessive?
3. Further, I still have a hard time in dealing with the the geometrical picture of those functional basis. I think I saw somewhere Spherical Harmonic was represented with a vector on a sphere aiming at $m,(m-1),...,-m$. However, how could we visualize associated Legendre polynomials? Does those $m$ represented the similar thing?

Could you in help me to distinguish the usage of those function basis, please?

Comment: You should start from the $x=\sin\theta,y+iz=e^{i\phi}\cos\theta$ parametrization of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, find the natural inner product (invariant under rotations), the Fourier series and Legendre polynomials inner products appear, thus obtaining the $L^2$ orthogonal basis $e^{im\phi}P_l(\cos(\theta))$, multiply with $\sin(\theta)^m$ it becomes an homogeneous polynomial $Y_l^m$ of $x,y,z$ and (from Legendre polynomials differential equation) it satisfies $(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2)Y_l^m=0$, from there it suffices to show it is $L^2$-complete in the harmonic functions.